# Android: Check if my app is allowed to run background activities

Tags: java, android, notifications, background-service, foreground-service

I have an app that runs a stopwatch service, and I run the service in the foreground.
I have a notification showing the timer, that updates each second.
The notification stops updating 30 seconds after I leave the app, and I figured out that the cause is my device's battery optimization:
Inside my app's system settings, there is a battery optimization section, that contains a setting called `Allow background activity`, which can be on or off.
I found 2 threads ([answer to thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56047564/8099601) and [answer to thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66183449/8099601)) trying to answer how to check the setting's state, and both of them suggest using `ActivityManager.isBackgroundRestricted`.
For me, it didn't work though. Whether the setting was switched On or Off, this function returned `false`.
How can I **check if my app is allowed to run background activities**?

Here's a photo of the setting in my phone (OnePlus 8t OxygenOS 12):
[image: system settings of my app]

Comment: Unclear if you are aware of: https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus

Comment: @MorrisonChang Wasn't actually aware of all of these, but only some of them, and I didn't think it was mainly OnePlus's issue. After all, the device referred to in the first thread was a Samsung if I'm not mistaken. and this doesn't solve my problem, I need to know how to do all these steps programmatically, make my app suitable for any device out there, or at least most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that it does not work for me also. So, you can see my two classes in my Git repo which I had also provided you within [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758160/android-notification-shows-in-delay-and-stops-updating-when-app-closed-for-30-s/71840843#71840843). Also my repo link is [here](https://github.com/sambhav2358/Backgroud-Stopwatch-Android). Here you must see [this](https://github.com/sambhav2358/Backgroud-Stopwatch-Android/blob/f4db90771047fbc99bff3e07a3ed888758230f5e/Stop%20watch/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L6) in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and [this](https://github.com/sambhav2358/Backgroud-Stopwatch-Android/blob/f4db90771047fbc99bff3e07a3ed888758230f5e/Stop%20watch/app/src/main/java/com/sambhav2358/testing/MainActivity.java#L87) method and [this](https://github.com/sambhav2358/Backgroud-Stopwatch-Android/blob/f4db90771047fbc99bff3e07a3ed888758230f5e/Stop%20watch/app/src/main/java/com/sambhav2358/testing/MainActivity.java#L148) overridden method.

There I am asking for the ignore battery optimization permission and if it is enabled, it works fine or it if not enabled, asks for that permission.

Also, you can view the result in relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71758160/17133283) question's answer. [This](https://www.veed.io/view/f2160914-e6a9-41c6-88d5-0cb00bf0109d) is the result

---

If that does not work, refer to this code:

```java
String packageName = getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "no allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // it is not enabled. Ask the user to do so from the settings.
}else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // good news! It works fine even in the background.
}
```

And to take the user to this setting's page, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098293/8099601):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
String expandedNotificationText = String.format("Background activity is restricted on this device.\nPlease allow it so we can post an active notification during work sessions.\n\nTo do so, click on the notification to go to\nApp management -> search for %s -> Battery Usage -> enable 'Allow background activity')", getString(R.string.app_name));
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setContentText("Background activity is restricted on this device.")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(expandedNotificationText))
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long wait. It doesn't work for me ):

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy Huh? That's surprising. Does it even ask for permission if not enabled?

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy Let me try on my one plus 9 r device. Maybe I encounter the issue there !

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy Hmmm. Even I encounter that issue. But, let me check if the notification stops updating or not. But, the first issue which you told in your question is not seen. Ahaa. The second issue has come up now. Let me check it out. Also for me the timer stops running

Comment: WOWOWOWOWOWOWOWOW. I found it man. I will edit my post now. Just 5 mins @NitzanDaloomy

Comment: Yes!!!! that's it!! thank you so much (((:
now I'll try to make an intent that redirects the user to this setting... do you have a clue how can I do that?

Comment: No idea. I saw all the actions in the intent class and found nothing

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find it, thanks(:
also, could you check my answer to the previous question? I've edited it because of some other issues that came up with the background-activities enabling.

Comment: ok. sure. 5 mins

Comment: Hi! found the way to make an intent that redirects the user to this setting!!
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
it's taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098293/8099601), and it'd be best if you could add this to your answer. I'd suggest an edit to your answer.

Comment: I did briefly. Should've I seen something in particular?

Comment: @NitzanDaloomy No. Only abt the action buttons I have added for the notification

Comment: Yes. That is why I wanted u to see that. Run the entire app and see the magic

Comment: I've seen it running in the video you posted(:

Comment: That's not the entire app. It does not have the action buttons and does not have a good ui.

Comment: Huh, I see
I've already added buttons to my notification, and I try opening an activity from outside the app using the notification but I cant do it. I already added the right flag needed for this but still it doesn't work for me. I'll understand to figure out why

Comment: Thats sus. It worked fine for me and it opened the activity also. Lets see that.

Comment: Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71911095/8099601), maybe you'll be able to help (: