# Android: Start an Activity from a Service when app is killed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, service

In my app, I have a `Service` running in the background (and foreground).

In this `Service`, there's a `CountdownTimer` and when it finishes I want to launch the app in a certain `Activity` and do some stuff in the `Activity` automatically, and I want this to work even if my app is killed or closed.

I've seen some answers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3607934/8099601) is one of them, but it won't work for me. I've found a better solution and posted it as an answer below, but still, it works only if the app is closed but not completely killed.

How can I launch an `Activity` from a background `Service` even when the app is closed or killed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start service in FOREGROUND_SERVICE
Like this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppService.class);
        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(intent);
    }
```

And Add This line in Main.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `AppService`?

Comment: AppService.class is his class to do some work what you wan to

Answer (score 0):

As `NitzanDaloomy` suggested in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71998323/17133283) we can use `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` but that won't open the app when it is killed but bring it in the recents list. Now, because our app is no longer closed(it is in background), we can use `startActivity(Intent intent)` and then, the app will open

Comment: and if it was not killed, it would open it twice, wouldn't it?

Comment: I dont think so. U can try it

Comment: Tried it... the activity won't open, the app stays closed but is visible in the recent apps.

Comment: Hmmm. I will look into it. But then i dont think u need to do such a thing. That is why android doesn't allow it

Comment: Anyway, it'd be great to have it... until a solution will appear, I'll just move on, of course. I've got to another issue, and I'd share a question soon (:

Comment: Will wait for it 

Comment: shared [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72089298/8099601) just now (:

Comment: Thanks. I will let u know tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59067224/8099601).
This answer suggests enabling `ScreeanOverlay` settings because as of Android 10 and later you can no longer open an activity from the background just by calling the lines I've used.
To make it work, you'd have to add this permission through your `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

And then the user would have to enable the `Display over other apps` setting.
I searched for an option to get the user to this setting more easily and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355440/8099601).
This answer gives a code that redirects the user to the `Display over other apps` setting

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

and then I guide the user with the notification's content (text) on how to enable the setting.
Once the setting is enabled, The lines I've used before work.\

So, problem solved?

### Not Completely Solved

this whole configuration described above works, but only if the app is not killed.
If the app was killed and I try the method listed above, the app joins the recent apps list, but won't open and show up.

Answer (score -1):

You need to request and enable overlay permission for your app to achieve that. Without that, your app cannot lunch any activity on the screen when it is in the foreground.

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it after seeing the response from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76111879/8519058)