# Android: Changing Views visibility on Activity start | Hide Notification panel on Notification Button click

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, visibility

My app has a `Notification` that holds a `Button`.

When the user clicks the `Button`, the app should open (if it was closed) and show a custom dialog, which I've created by a bunch of views.

Showing the dialog means setting its `Visibility` to `View.VISIBLE`.

I use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the `Notification`s `Button` click, and it works (I've used `Toast` messages to check it, and it does - the `Receiver` is getting called when the `Button` is clicked, and it reaches to the function that changes the dialogs `Visibility` to `View.VISIBLE`)

When I click the `Button`, the app does open, but the dialog won't show.

Also, I've noticed that when I click the `Button`, the `Notification` panel does not hide (unlike when clicking the `Notification` itself), and I thought maybe it has something to do with it.

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420509/8099601) answer, but it didn't work for me (below there's another answer, much newer, but I didn't understand what he did there or how can I do it).

I also checked using `Toast` messages whether the `Visibility` parameter of the dialog is changing or not, and it is changing to `View.VISIBLE` (0), and still, the dialog is not shown.
If I'm in the app and trying to show the dialog, it works, the dialog shows on an in-app button click, the issue occurs when trying to show the dialog as soon as opening the app using the `Notification`s `Button` click

Is the `Notification Panel` the problem?
If it is, why is it happening and how can I hide the notification panel?
If it's not, what is it, and how can I solve this?

### Edit

I was asked for the code that inits and shows the notification, so here it is:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void updateNotification() {
    isBatteryOptimizationActive = App.isBatteryOptimizationActive();

    clearAllTimerNotificationActionButtons();

    if (isBatteryOptimizationActive) {
        initBatteryOptimizationActiveNotification();
    } else {
        if (notificationJustStarted) {
            initNotificationBase();
        }
        initAndStartPomodoroTimerNotification();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.notify(TIMER_NOTIFICATION_ID, pomodoroNotificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
private void initNotificationBase() {
    pomodoroNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    pomodoroNotificationBuilder
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.timer_notification_background_allowed_title))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tomato)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setNotificationSilent()
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    notificationJustStarted = false;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void initAndStartTimerNotification() {
    String enableScreenOverlayText = "",
            actionButtonTitle;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        /** Initialize the notification in case "draw over other apps" setting is disabled */
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        actionButtonTitle = "Enable";
        enableScreenOverlayText = String.format("To be able stopping the timer from the notification:\nClick Enable -> Search for %s -> Allow Display over other apps", getString(R.string.app_name));
    } else {
        /** Initialize the notification in case "draw over other apps" setting is enabled */
        Intent stopActionIntent = new Intent(this, PomodoroService.class);
        stopActionIntent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
        stopActionIntent.putExtra(POMODORO_SERVICE_STOP_FOR_REAL_EXTRA_NAME, false);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, stopActionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        actionButtonTitle = "Stop";
    }


    pomodoroNotificationBuilder
            .setContentText(String.format("%s is in progress\nThis session remains: %s until finished", goalName, PublicMethods.formatStopWatchTime(millisRemaining)))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(enableScreenOverlayText))
            .addAction(R.drawable.stop, actionButtonTitle, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of what you try to show the notification?

Comment: I don't understand... the code that initializes the notification and shows it?

Comment: Yes. That is it

Comment: just a moment, I'll do it. can you get into the chat I've opened?

Comment: Where is it? I could not find it

Comment: nevermind, I'd close the chat... but I actually recall sharing this code with you in the previous questions, didn't I?

Comment: Its the same u use? Can u share it here also pls. It makes it easy to navigate

Comment: it is the same use... I'll share it though, sure

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0):

> How can I hide the notification panel?

I see that you are receiving the action button click in the Receiver. So, then it becomes an easy task to dismiss it. In the receiver, add this line:

```java
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.cancel(TIMER_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

---

> When I click the Button, the app does open, but the dialog won't show.

You need to pass an intent extra that you are wanting to show the dialog. Then, you can, in the `onCreate()` get that extra and then show the dialog accordingly.

Comment: I'm already using intent with this extra, and in the receiver, I'm calling the function that shows the dialog.
Do you believe that I should somehow move it to the `onCreate()` method?

Comment: I don't correctly get you. How can you set the visibility of a dialogue to visible it can only be shown and hidden

Comment: what do you mean? as I explained in my question, the dialog is custom, meaning that it's just a bunch of views glued up to create the dialog... I change the visibility of the "parent view" of the dialog to toggle its visibility

Comment: and about the notification panel, I think you didn't understand me there as well. if I'm not wrong, I think the code you suggested is supposed to dismiss my app's specific notification, and I seek to hide the whole notification *panel*...

Comment: This conversation has been **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244405/android-changing-views-visibility-on-activity-start-hide-notification-panel-on)**

Comment: Waiting for your response in the chat @NitzanDaloomy.

Comment: you got it. again, I think you don't understand how's my dialog working. it is *not* a regular dialog, it's just a bunch of views that I store inside a parent view, and together they function as a custom dialog of myself...

Comment: Ok. I get you correctly now @NitzanDaloomy. Can you share the code of how the view is being set to visible in the chat above or in the question? Also share the condition you have used to set the visibility to visible of gone

Comment: I don't understand which code you want me to share

Comment: When the activity opens, you are checking whether the action or extra is there or not. If yes, set it to visible or gone right? I want that code